# Taking screenshot from Petrel child windows

Tags: ocean, petrel

Is it possible to take screenshot of Petrel's child windows (programmatically) from the plugin using Ocean 2014.1? At the moment, I can save BMP for Window3D and EMF for other derives of ToggleWindow and read them again from my plugin, but, this doesn't work for all Petrel's child windows. Also, I would prefer to get raster image (like what I get when I push on Camera button action in Clipboard action group, Home tab) and support other windows like Histogram Window, Plot Window, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think Ocean has a common API that does what you want.

As you found out, some windows have methods that allow you to capture an Image dump of the window, but it is far from being generic.